# changing adress of pointer created using malloc

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand how malloc and pointer works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int *p;
    int b = 15;
    p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        p + i = &b;
    }
}
```

The above code gives error 
**expression is not assignable
p + i = &b;**

As far as  I understand, malloc gives the starting address of the memory allocated in heap which I typecast to hold the address of integers. So technically, p + i should be able to hold any integer address, but the code throws an error. Can you please explain why this is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `*(p + i)`?  (Or perhaps `p[i]`?)

Comment: Major confusion here, Firstly, `p + i` is an expression, which cannot be an **l-value**. Secondly, the memory pointed by `p + i` can hold integer, which can be done using `*(p + i)`, but you are trying to make it hold `int *`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. int b = 25; int *a = &b; int c = 50; a = &c. When the above code works, why doesn't the one allocated by malloc in the question doesn't work.  The memory pointed by p + i can hold integer. Then why can't I change p + i to point to the address of an integer.

Comment: Please don't cast the return of `malloc` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code `p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);` means that the pointer p is assigned the address of the first element of the dynamically allocated array with `malloc()`,which has allocated an `int` array consisting of 10 elements.

If you want to assign 5 of these elements the value of `b` then you write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    p[i] = b;
}
```

If however you want an array of 10 integer pointers and want to assign 5 of them the address of `b`,then you write:

```
int **pointer = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pointer[i] = &b;
}
```

Don't forget to free dynamically allocated memory when you finish.

Answer (score 0):

`p + i` is pointing to an address on your memory, the same as `&(p[i])`. You can't change the address of the memory, so that's why the compiler is saying the expression is not assignable.

If you want to save an `int` on that address you need to use `*(p+i) = b`.

But if you want to save the address of an `int` you need an array which holds `int*`, so you need to declare `p` as an `int**` and allocate its memory with the `sizeof(int*)`. That way your code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int **p;
    int b = 15;
    p = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        *(p + i) = &b;
    }
}
```